# How can I automatically save images in different folder with CK Finder 3

Tags: php, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckfinder

I am having difficulty getting this newer version of CKFinder (CKFinder 3) to work like how the old version did. The system used to automatically detect image files and store them in an "images" subfolder and for all other files, in a "files" subfolder.

It now seems the images subfolder only gets files to saved to it when you navigate to the folder in the "browse server" popup window and add files after clicking on the images folder. Uploading and clicking "Send to server" also sends all files to the "files" subfolder regardless of filetype.

The major problem with this is it ignores the file-size rules that are set-up for images, unless you navigate to the images folder, and then it will enforce it. It also is much less convenient as the user will not likely navigate to the subfolder each time.

Currently I have setup the config.php for CKFinder 3 like so:

```
$config['backends'][] = array(
    'name'         => 'default',
    'adapter'      => 'local',
    'baseUrl'      => $baseDir, // "/mywebsite/sites/default/uploads/"
    //'root'         => '', // Can be used to explicitly set the CKFinder user files directory.
    'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
    'chmodFolders' => 0755,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
);


/*================================ Resource Types =====================================*/
// https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_resourceTypes

$config['defaultResourceTypes'] = '';

$config['resourceTypes'][] = array(
    'name'              => 'Files', // Single quotes not allowed.
    'directory'         => '/files/',
    'maxSize'           => '10M',
    'allowedExtensions' => '7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gz,gzip,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip,gif,jpeg,jpg,png,svg',
    'deniedExtensions'  => '',
    'backend'           => 'default',
);

$config['resourceTypes'][] = array(
    'name'              => 'Images',
    'directory'         => '/images/',
    'maxSize'           => '500K',
    'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png,svg',
    'deniedExtensions'  => '',
    'backend'           => 'default',
);
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The system used to automatically detect image files and store them in an "images" subfolder and for all other files, in a "files" subfolder.

This is not correct, CKFinder never worked like this. Although, you can achieve such behavior using a connector plugin.

Let's say I want all the uploaded images to be placed in `Images:/` and other files should go to `Files:/`.

```php
<?php

// plugins/MyPlugin/MyPlugin.php

namespace CKSource\CKFinder\Plugin\MyPlugin;

use CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Event\BeforeCommandEvent;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Event\CKFinderEvent;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Image;
use CKSource\CKFinder\Plugin\PluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class MyPlugin implements PluginInterface, EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function setContainer(CKFinder $app) {}

    public function getDefaultConfig() {
        return [];
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            CKFinderEvent::BEFORE_COMMAND_FILE_UPLOAD => 'handleBeforeFileUpload',
            CKFinderEvent::BEFORE_COMMAND_QUICK_UPLOAD => 'handleBeforeFileUpload'
        ];
    }

    public function handleBeforeFileUpload(BeforeCommandEvent $event) {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
        $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('upload');

        if ($uploadedFile && $uploadedFile->isValid()) {
            $resourceType = 'Files';

            if (Image::isSupportedExtension($uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension())) {
                $resourceType = 'Images';
            }

            $request->query->set('type', $resourceType);
            $request->query->set('currentFolder', '/');
        }
    }
}
```

Save the above plugin code as `plugins/MyPlugin/MyPlugin.php` and enable it in `config.php`:

```
$config['plugins'] = ['MyPlugin'];
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, thank you so much. I must have been using a plugin with my old version of CKFinder that was doing this for me behind the scenes. One small quirk i noticed with this solution is that the "Upload" tab before the big CK Finder window comes up has a "Send to Server" option. This "Send to Server" button still throws everything into that files directory. Do you have any idea how I could make that work the same way?

Comment: @Wallaaa: Uploads from CKEditor use a separate command named `QuickUpload`. I have modified the answer and added the following line: `CKFinderEvent::BEFORE_COMMAND_QUICK_UPLOAD => 'handleBeforeFileUpload'`. That should do the trick.

Comment: This works great, that new plugin code fixes that issue. Thanks again Zaak!